# Not able to start MariaDB on Centos 7

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos7

I have the latest release of Centos 7 and MariaDB. I wanted to change the password for the database users and I run this command:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

I pressed Enter on my PC and I logged out by closing Putty as it was taking a while and I have changed my mind regarding the command.

Now, the MariaDB is not working and I cant start it with:

```
systemctl mariadb start
```

Comment: What error is shown when you try to start mariadb?

Comment: It does not show any error. I enter "systemctl start mariadb", it looks like it does that fast, but then the MariaDB does not work. "systemctl status mariadb shows that it cant start /usr/bin/mysqld_safe. I was looking at the list of the processes with "ps aux | grep mysql | less" and I was thinking about killing the two processes that show there, or maybe just one, which is the "mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking" command that I run.

Comment: It may look as I logged out and this command was still running after I logged in again (with Putty) and this prevents the MariaDB from starting with "systemctl start mariadb"

Comment: http://prntscr.com/cs14tp

Comment: I was thinking kill these two manually and then try again with the "systemctl start mariadb" command?

Comment: RESOLVED: mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown, <password here>, systemctl start mariadb